# How i should rewrite Lodash filter method to Ramda filter?

Tags: javascript, lodash, ramda.js

**type horizontalLines = Array < ReactTestInstance >**

`const horizontalLines = _.filter(lines, {props: {height: '1'}});`

Comment: Maybe you should read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Answer (score 2):

Ramda's functions tend to have simpler signatures that do those from lodash.  There aren't many places where you could pass either a function or an object to configure a function as this lodash function does.  But there are plenty of ways to do this.  You just need to combine more of Ramda's primitive functions.

Here are two solutions that should work:

```
filter(pathEq(['props', 'height'], '1'), lines)

filter(where({props: whereEq({height: '1'})}), lines)
```